# Determining if white LEDs are eye safe for direct eye exposure

Tags: led, safety

I am looking at buying lots of LEDs for a signboard hobby project. This is my first project using LEDs and I wanted to make sure (and learn) that I am making a safe project.

The LEDs I am looking at right now are Samsung's mid-power [LM281BA+ LEDs](https://led.samsung.com/lighting/mid-power-leds/2835-leds/lm281ba-plus/) since they are so cheap. These are 0.2W and 3V with a luminous flux of 26.5 @ 60mA (not exactly sure how to interpret luminous flux for eye safety). From the datasheet, it appears the beam angle is typically 120 degrees.

The Samsung page I linked above contains a link to a document under the label ["Eye Safety: LM281BA+ S3 Rank IEC 62471 (IEC 62778)."](https://led.samsung.com/lighting/mid-power-leds/2835-leds/lm281ba-plus/). The document is quite verbose and hard to interpret. Page 9 has information with a conclusion of "pass" in reference to some measurement.

From what I can gather, there are certain risk groups that an LED can fall into defined by IEC 62471 (IEC 62778). Page 3 of this [document](https://smartvisionlights.com/wp-content/uploads/IEC_62471_summary.pdf) by a different company explains the different risk groups the LED can be within.

My question essentially boils down to, how do I interpret the published Samsung results to know what risk groups the LM281BA+ is in? What should I know about/do for the LEDs to ensure that they are never driven to a point that could hurt someone's vision?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I think this is a tough question and likely won't get you a perfect answer here. Though perhaps some thoughts. We already know from recent research that chronic exposure to blue LED lights have documented harms. And that's within the visual range. That LED looks like phosphors are used (not RGB) and that implies higher-energy photons being used (and possibly leaked very slightly through the phosphors.) Depending on phosphor mix, plus LED itself, there may be quite a combination of wavelengths as well as mode-mixing and dispersion angles. I'd suggest asking a professional for next-steps advice.

Comment: @periblepsis do you know of any professionals I could contact? I'm having trouble finding anything online that get me to someone who could answer my question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I spent years studying and working with Siemens/OSRAM (LED manufacturing in Penang.) Part of that required knowledge of hue+brightness sensations in the human eye. Which means a small exposure also to related biological mechanisms of the eye. Part of that required a solid grounding in optical systems. And yes, those I worked with would be good choices here. But they are retired, near dead, or dead, now. And I've been out of the area for almost 20 years. You want someone who can correctly interpret related biological  research studies as well as provide correct optical measurement setups.

Comment: I think you should contact the manufacturer of the LEDs you are considering and ask them. They should already have such professionals on tap (Siemens/OSRAM sure did) and even if they aren't willing to hire them out to you or "legally conflict them", they should be able to ask those experts for some peers they respect. Make the call and if you find any resistance be stubborn about it. Don't give in until they deliver. They really have no possible valid excuse for not being helpful. And if they feign ignorance then you know they are lying. No way they make these things without deep knowledge.

Comment: That's actually where I was headed next. I'll post back here if I get an answer.

Again, thanks for sharing what knowledge you have and taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: I'd love to hear about it!! And thanks so much for considering the idea of reporting back. :)